# How can I make a sharp looking axe?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Can I somehow make my axe look "sharper" in cycles nodes?

[image: axe]

Comment: Suggestion.  Place an image of an axe that appears sharp to you in the question.  Also place your artwork in the same position.  Free images on the internet should have one example that agrees with your concept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

U could make a texture that makes the edges more bright as you see it on real axes:

[image: Real axe]

Here the quick setup - maybe it can help
[image: setup]

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to accomplish this. The answer involves more than nodes in Cycles. It includes the geometry of the axe head, lighting and yes materials.

Reference images are very helpful. A quick web search of “sharp axes” for example will return a lot of reference images to consider.

-The leading edge of an axe has an angle to it. The angle varies depending on the type of axe. Incorporating this angle into you geometry will help your axe to look sharp.

[image]

-Adjusting your lighting to get a reflection and/or highlight on the axes leading edge will also help to give the impression of sharpness.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics)

-A simple node setup to start with:
Select your axe head create a new material. I’ll name it Axe.Body

[image]

Click the “+” icon in the Material pane to add a second material. I’ll name it Axe.Edge.
In “Edit” mode select the faces that represent the leading edge of the axe then click “Assign”.

[image]

In the node editor add a Glossy Shader and a Mix Shader. The “Fac” variable of the Mix Shader determines the balance of Glossy to Diffuse. 1 = all glossy and 0 = all diffuse .5 would be an equal mix. The “Roughness” variable of the Glossy Shader also plays a part in the material surface.

[image]

[image]